# Vaadin modify IndexHtmlResponse to set meta tags

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

In order to improve SEO of my Vaadin application I'd like to set up custom meta tags.

For this purpose I'd like to use `IndexHtmlRequestListener`:

```
serviceInitEvent.addIndexHtmlRequestListener(new IndexHtmlRequestListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyIndexHtmlResponse(IndexHtmlResponse indexHtmlResponse) {

                Optional<UI> optionalUI = indexHtmlResponse.getUI();

                if (optionalUI.isPresent()) {
                    UI ui = optionalUI.get();
                    Document document = indexHtmlResponse.getDocument();

                    String title = ui.getInternals().getTitle();
                    if(StringUtils.isNoneBlank(title)) {
                        setMetaTag(document, "og:title", title);
                    }

                    setMetaTag(document, "description", ...
                    setMetaTag(document, "og:image", ...
                }
            }

        });

}
```

As you may see, right now I'm able to get the title provided in the every single view via `HasDynamicTitle` interface. I'd like to follow the same schema for the rest of meta tags. Simply speaking - I want to define such set of tags in the every view and then be able to retrieve somehow such tags in  `modifyIndexHtmlResponse` method and set up these values to the document meta tags.

Please advice how to access the current `View` instance from the `modifyIndexHtmlResponse` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a fully initialized UI instance, you can find the current view (along with any wrapping router layouts) from the list in `ui.getInternals().getActiveRouterTargetsChain()`.

Answer (score 1):

The IndexHtmlRequestListener is invoked when the application is bootstrapped during the very first request to the server; you shouldn't assume a View exists at this stage. What you can do is access the `VaadinRequest` from the `IndexHtmlResponse` object, and that will give you the request path via `getPathInfo`. You should be able to deduce the headers you want to add based on that.

Comment: I believe the view is initialized if the `eagerServerLoad` property is set to `true`, and only then will `getUI()` be non-empty.

Comment: Yes, and it defaults to false.

Comment: I'm assuming that if the example code is effective, then the poster has already set it to true.

Comment: yes, I already set `vaadin.eagerServerLoad=true`. The biggest issue with the approach, based on the request path - is that I have to query the database at least twice. For example, on the Job page - with this approach, I'll have to query db for the job description once in `modifyIndexHtmlResponse` (for meta tag) and also in the Job View (for job page content). This why I'd like to avoid it and reuse the job object from the View in the `modifyIndexHtmlResponse`

Comment: Presuming the values needed for your meta tags don't change that often, you could cache the values from the database in an Application-scoped bean or a static variable.